# I'm trying to understand array_merge() function

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting these results in that order ...

> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }
>
> WARNING array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array on line number 12
>
> NULL
>
> WARNING array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array on line number 14
>
> NULL

And I'm trying to understand why ..

Here is my code :

```
$referenceTable = array();
$referenceTable['val1'] = array(1, 2);
$referenceTable['val2'] = 3;
$referenceTable['val3'] = array(4, 5);

$testArray = array();

$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val1']);
var_dump($testArray);
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2']);
var_dump($testArray);
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val3']);
var_dump($testArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that, if either the first or second argument to `array_merge()` is not an array, the return value will be `NULL`

As a result, the call to `$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2'])` evaluates to `$testArray = array_merge($testArray, 3)` and, since `3` is not of type `array`, this call to `array_merge()` returns `NULL`, which in turn ends up setting `$testArray` equal to `NULL`. Then, when we get to the next call to `array_merge()`, `$testArray` is now `NULL` so `array_merge()` again returns `NULL`.

The fix for this is straightforward. If we simply typecast the second argument to an array, we will get the desired results. The corrected `array_merge()` calls would therefore be as follows:

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, (array)$referenceTable['val1']);
var_dump($testArray);
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, (array)$referenceTable['val2']);
var_dump($testArray);
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, (array)$referenceTable['val3']);
var_dump($testArray);
```

which will yield the following output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) } 
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } 
array(5) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> int(4) [4]=> int(5) }
```